# Suddenly cannot open any terminal on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, gnome-terminal

I suddenly cannot open a gnome-terminal window in Linux Mint. I installed xterm and guake too now looking for a replacement, but none of them will open either.

When I do try to open gnome-terminal by any method, the window will flash on the screen, but then it instantly closes before I can really see anything. My .xsession-error file is completely full of different messages, but the following is an example of what seems to be triggered directly when I try to open gnome-terminal.

```
Window manager warning: Log level 16: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.36.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2593: instance `0xacf1710' has no handler with id `17056'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.36.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2593: instance `0xacf1710' has no handler with id `17057'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.36.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2593: instance `0xaa1ae80' has no handler with id `17102'
Window manager warning: Log level 16: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.36.0/./gobject/gsignal.c:2593: instance `0xaa1ae80' has no handler with id `17103'
    JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was: Error: got a _calcWindowNumber callback but this._appButton is undefined
    JS ERROR: !!!   Exception was a String
      JS LOG: AppTrackerError: get_window_app returned null and there was no record of metaWindow in internal database
```

Guake behaves similarly. With xterm, I see nothing at all... no window and no new error messages. The eshell inside emacs and the command executer associated with Alt+F2 both seem to be working fine.

Comment: "_My .xsession-error file is completely full of different messages_" ... How big is it? If you're just a normal user, it shouldn't be more than a few lines.

Comment: At the moment it has 1088 lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found the answer on my own. I had done something to my `/etc/passwd/` file, without really understanding what I was doing. Restoring that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: let's just say lol

Comment: Hey... you were a n00b once too.

Comment: that's true and I'm still is in fact :D