# Cannot open any terminal window

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have been using Mint 17.2 for over a month with no problems, but today for reasons I can't explain the terminal window won't open. When I launch it it immediately closes the window before initializing.

I did not do any upgrades or system modifications recently, I was just using the web & email today when the system froze (this has happened before and it's never been a big deal) but after reboot I have this problem with the terminal.

So far I've:

- Rebooted a few more times
- Ran pending updates (not much; installed fine but didn't help)
- Installed xterm as an alternative, but it does the same thing
- Tried the terminal built into my IDE - it too won't open
- Searched the web for this scenario - found [this post with the same reported symptom](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105273/suddenly-cannot-open-any-terminal-on-linux-mint) but otherwise doesn't seem related

Any recommendations for how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Try switching to a VT (`Ctrl-Alt-F3` will do it) and logging in with your username and password.

Comment: Thanks @TomHunt - logging in would flash the welcome message for an instant then return me to the login prompt. I eventually tracked the problem to my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out - an app I recently installed apparently had introduced a syntax error into my `~/.bashrc` file. Reverting that fixed the problem.

Comment: what app are you referring to?

Comment: [Drush 8](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) - running the command `drush init` modifies the .bashrc file, haven't dug deeply enough to know what's wrong with the lines it adds, but they are definitely the ones that crashed my terminal.